# My 301 Redirect redirects without slash after the .dot

Tags: php

We just copied our site to a new url. To preserve the links we're trying to 301 redirect the old urls to the new website.

My htacces code looks like this

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.bpmverhuur.nl
Redirect 301 /verhuur-grondverzet-minigraver-15ton-verhuur/ https://bpmverhuur.nl/verhuur-grondverzet-minigraver-15ton-verhuur/
```

When navigating to the initial link, the browser redirects me to:

https://www.bpmverhuur.nlverhuur-grondverzet-minigraver-15ton-verhuur
This misses the slash after the .nl
How could I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect: _“The old URL-path is a case-sensitive (%-decoded) path beginning with a slash. A relative path is not allowed.”_ - you did not specify a URL path, but a full, absolute URL incl. scheme and host name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Redirect 301 /verhuur-grondverzet-minigraver-15ton-verhuur/ https://bpmverhuur.nl/verhuur-grondverzet-minigraver-15ton-verhuur/
```

Comment: Your solution still redirects me to the new url without slash after the dot NL. I updated my original post because I saw I had the Redirect 301 / https://www.bpmverhuur.nl above the redirect. 

Could this influence the redirect?

Comment: `Redirect 301 / https://www.bpmverhuur.nl` is entire domain redirect. If you append slash `/` in the end of requested page. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `URL-path` argument for `Redirect` is treated as a *prefix*.

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.bpmverhuur.nl
```

So this affects *all* requests that start with `/`.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect:

> Then any request beginning with URL-path will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL. Additional path information beyond the matched URL-path will be appended to the target URL.

This means, if `/foobar` gets requested, the *additional path information beyond the matched URL-path*  will be just `foobar`. And you specified `https://www.bpmverhuur.nl` as the base this should be appended to, so you end up with `https://www.bpmverhuur.nlfoobar`. So you should add a trailing slash to this base, to fix that issue.

And then switch the order of your directives - so that `/verhuur-grondverzet-minigraver-15ton-verhuur/` gets taken care of first. You need to go most specific first, less specific later.